# How to split string with ',' with a condition in regex java

Tags: regex

I want to split a string using regex in java with ',' as delimiter with a condition. it will be a delimiter if only there is one '=' character before next ','.

ex :

```
    String test = "APPLICATION:1:1=SECTOR,APPLICATION:2:1=INDUSTRY,DESCRIPT:1:1=Sec,tor,DESCRIPT:2:1=Industry,"
    String [] testRegex = test.split(????)
```

the value of testRegex should be :

```
     APPLICATION:1:1=SECTOR
     APPLICATION:2:1=INDUSTRY
     DESCRIPT:1:1=Sec,tor
     DESCRIPT:2:1=Industry
```

is there any idea for the regex? i can't find any example yet till now :(

Comment: I doubt your title expresses what you actually want. If you split the string with any comma, it won't work. Have you tried any expression yet? Do the keys always follow the `ALNUMS:DIGITS:DIGITS` pattern?

Comment: Hi, sorry i'm kind a new to regex, don't have any idea for this case

Comment: Ok, so the idea is: match `,` that is followed with `ALNUMS:DIGITS:DIGITS` or end of string.

Comment: Is it always upper alphas that are right next to the commas where you want to split? If so, try eg like this pattern: [`,(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/OmU2kQ/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble the alphas cannot be the border, it can be a upper or lower case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my idea is : ',' will be a delimiter if only there is '=' in the next value group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If separator comma should be followed by a part containing equal sign, you may use positive lookahead.

```
String parts[] = yourString.split(",(?=[^,]*=)");
```

(?=) is used for positive lookahead. It wont be used for split, it is just an assertion and will be discarded from match.

Comment: @yavuzkavuz That works! Thank you Sir for the explanation :)

Comment: @bobblebubble it also works after remove that one. Thank You :)

Comment: This solution does not remove the trailing comma from the last item. The regex must match the `,` at the end of the string, too, to fix that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you are right. If it is necessary, maybe something like **split(",(?:(?=[^,]*=)|$)")** can be used.